# Why does rbenv still work even though I'm not prepending to my PATH?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I was reading through some of the rbenv documentation to try to wrap mind mind around how it works and I read the following:

> rbenv works by inserting a directory of shims at the front of your
>   PATH:
>
> ~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin Through a process called
>   rehashing, rbenv maintains shims in that directory to match every Ruby
>   command across every installed version of Ruby—irb, gem, rake, rails,
>   ruby, and so on.

I'm currently able to use rbenv successfully to switch between different versions of ruby:

```
~/.rbenv/versions ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin15.0]
~/.rbenv/versions rbenv versions    
  system
* 2.1.5 (set by /Users/max/.rbenv/version)
  2.2.3
~/.rbenv/versions rbenv global 2.2.3
~/.rbenv/versions rbenv rehash
~/.rbenv/versions ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]
~/.rbenv/versions rbenv global 2.1.5
~/.rbenv/versions rbenv rehash
~/.rbenv/versions ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin15.0]
```

But then when I looked inside my ~/.zshrc file I found the following:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin"
```

which seems like rbenv hasn't prepended anything and it's actually appended which according to the documentation makes it seem like it wouldn't work and my system would look into /usr/bin and find my system ruby executable and run it instead of the ones that I have inside /Users/max/.rbenv/versions. But that's obviously not what is happening, so I'm wondering what's going on here? Am I missing something?

EDIT: I was just digging around more in my .zshrc file and I found this at the very bottom, probably from when I was trying to figure out how to get rbenv working the first time:

```
# Fix to rbenv
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Is this the line that is "prepending" as the documentation says? So it that case could is this mention of .rbenv in export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin" redundant?

Comment: What is your $PATH variable at runtime? Run `echo $PATH` and show us the results.

Comment: Thanks freedrull, this is what it looks like `/Users/max/.rbenv/shims:/Users/max/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/max/.rbenv/shims:/Users/max/.rbenv/bin` so it looks like yes at runtime it's all good, and I think it's because I prepended it in a different section of my zshrc see edit

Comment: Wrt your edit, yes that's likely the culprit, and yes the other is redundant.